# Beginner at Java, on the last if-else statement, i just cant figure out the "but not both " part

Tags: java, if-statement

```
import java.util.*;
public class Divisible {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Divisible by 5 and 6 or not
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        x = s.nextInt();
        if ((x % 5==0) && (x % 6==0)){
            System.out.print("is "+x+" divisible by 5 and 6? ");
            System.out.print("true");
        }else{
            System.out.print("is "+x+" divisible by 5 and 6? ");
            System.out.print("false");
        }// Divisible by 5 or 6
        if ((x % 5==0) || (x % 6==0)){
            System.out.print("\nIs "+x+" divisible by 5 or 6? ");
            System.out.print("true");
        }else{
            System.out.print("Is "+x+" divisible by 5 or 6? ");
            System.out.print("false");
        }// Divisible by 5 or 6,but not both
        if ((x % 5==0) || (x % 6==0)){ //here is my problem, i cant figure out the code for "not both" part 
            System.out.print("Is "+x+" divisible by 5 or 6, but not both? ");  
            System.out.print("true");
        }else{
            System.out.print("Is "+x+" divisible by 5 or 6, but not both? ");
            System.out.print("false");
        }

    }
}
```

i know my last if-else statement is wrong, i just cant figure out the coding for the last task witch is "Is "+x+" divisible by 5 or 6, ***but not both***? "

Thank you

Comment: this is not javascript

Comment: sorry if i messed up the question formula, i'm new here

Comment: ((x % 5==0) || (x % 6==0))  && !((x % 5==0) && (x % 6==0))

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following logic

```
if(x%5 == 0 && x%6 == 0){
 SOP("number is divisible by both 5 and 6);
}else{
   if(x%5 == 0){
     SOP("Number is divisible only by 5");
   }else if(x%6 == 0){
    SOP("Number is divisible only by 6");
   }else{
    SOP("Number is not divisible 5 nor by 6");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only slightly modified your code. Mainly, changed the if-else condition. The first if condition you can simply just put 30, which is the LCD(Least Common Denominator) of 5 and 6.

```
    System.out.println("is " + x + " divisible by 5 and 6? "); //Divisible by 5 and 6
    if ((x%30==0))
        System.out.println("true");
    else
        System.out.println("false");


    System.out.println("Is " + x +" divisible by 5 or 6? "); //Divisible by 5 or 6
    if (x%5==0 || x%6==0)
        System.out.println("true");
    else
        System.out.println("false");


    System.out.print("Is " + x + " divisible by 5 or 6, but not both? "); // Divisible by 5 or 6,but not both                                
    if ((x%5==0 && x%6!=0)
        System.out.println("true");
    else if(x%5!=0) && (x%6==0)
        System.out.println("true");
    else
        System.out.println("false");
```